# How to rename 'Quickfix' title powered by setloclist builtin function?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have a custom vim script, which navigate through files using `setloclist` builtin function. How to rename 'Quickfix' title right on the bottom of navigation file list and above command line?

[image]

Comment: `:help w:quickfix_title`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either set [`w:quickfix_title`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#w%3aquickfix_title) or use [`setloclist()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#setloclist%28%29) recent 4th `{what}` parameter.

You may need to update your vim version.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Not needless to mention, that popular `vim-powerline` plugin overwrite any default or custom (like in my case) `location list` or `quickfix list` by own title